# Using a default array when remaping a controller

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, routes, default-value

How to make the controller work same as the following two ways
`example.com/page/user1` and `example.com/page/user1/all`

```
public function _remap($slug = "",$params = array("all")){
    $sections = array("all","texts","photos");

    if ($slug != "" && in_array($params[0],$sections)) {                                                                            
      return $this->router($slug, $params[0]);
    }else{
      echo "something went wrong";
    }
  }
```

But `example.com/page/user1` gives an error (`Undefined offset: 0`). 
I need to do this without touching `config/routes.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quick fix is :

```
    $params[0] = count($params) == 0 ? "all" : $params[0];
```

Have you any suggestions ?